# Split the discord bot (Node.js process) across different Machines (Servers/VPSs)

Tags: node.js, process, discord.js, cluster-computing, sharding

So I was developing a discord bot (Using discord.js)
Recently my bot has reached 20k guilds
And my one VPS can't handle the pressure of all that servers (I'm already internally Sharding)
So I was wondering how can I split the nodejs process across different servers (Like one server will handle half the guilds and the other will handle the rest)

I tried googling and ended up with results showing `How to split an express app` which did not help at all.

I heard about the npm module `cluster` but after long research I found that it can run the app on different Process not different machines and I actually can't distribute the guilds with that.

Any help would be appreciated